# MVC RadiobuttonFor Razor how to make label click able?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I'm trying to make a radiobuttonlist in razor syntax so far I have come up with this

```
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <div id="projectList" class="col-lg-5">
        @Html.RadioButton("name", "1", false, new { onCLick = "ShowOption(this)", id = p.id.ToString() })
        @Html.Label(p.id.ToString(), p.name)
    </div>
}
```

but the label isn't associated with the radiobutton.

Comment: `<label>@Html.RadioButton(...)<span>@p.name</span></label>`

Comment: you are simply my hero! if you would post it as answer so i can make it as correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop is not generating `for` attribute for the label (and if you removed `new { id = p.id.ToString() }` from the `RadioButton` method, no `id` attribute would be added either despite it being the default behavior to do so.

The reason the attributes are not added when your model is `IEnumerable<T>` is to comply with the HTML-4 standards which state that

> ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z])

`HtmlHelpers` generate the `id` attribute based on the `name` attribute but replace and `[`, `]` and `.` characters with an underscore to prevent a conflict with `jQuery` selectors (e.g. a `.` in an `id` attribute would be interpreted as a class name selector). In your case the `name` is `name="[0].Name"` for the first item in the collection, but because that would mean generating `id="_0__Name"` (invalid in HTML-4), the `HtmlHelper` just omits the `id` (and in the case of a `label`, the `for` attribute.

A simple way to solve this is to just wrap the radio button in a `<label>` element

```
<label>
    @Html.RadioButton("name", "1", false)
    <span>@p.name</span>
</label>
```

Another option is to generate the `id` attribute in `RadioButton()` and also generate a matching `for` attribute in the label

```
@Html.RadioButton("name", "1", false, new { onclick = "ShowOption(this)", id = p.id })
@Html.Label(p.name, new { @for = p.id})
```

Side note: I recommend you use the stongly typed `RadioButtonFor()` and `LabelFor()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Look for this line 
@Html.Label("some label",htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "ShowOption("someID");", id = "someID" })

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ShowOption(id) {
 /* do something */
}
</script>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="https://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Getting started</h2>

            @Html.Label("some label",htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "ShowOption("someID");", id = "someID" })

            <p>
                ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
                enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
                for enjoyable, agile development.
            </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
            <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
            <p>You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```